# Plot the following parametric equation on latex using PSTricks:

Tags: xetex, pstricks, overleaf

x = (cos(t^2))*(1 - sint);
y = (sin(t^2))*(1 + cost); -2/pi ≤ t ≤ 2/pi ;
The following was my approach to this

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
\title{\textbf{\LARGE {Assignment}}}
\author{\emph {NEHA MALIK}}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,5)
\psaxes{<->}(0,0)(-4.5,-4.5)(4.5,4.5)
\psparametricplot[linecolor=green]{-360}{360}{t 2 exp cos 1 t sin sub mul t 2 exp sin 1 t cos add mul} 
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

I have to use only \psparametricplot for it and I am new to it. Can someone help??
I am attaching what I got and what the output graph should look like.
[image: First one is my output and next to it is the correct one.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us your short compilable tex code you have so far ...

Comment: here is what I tried:            \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,5)
\psaxes{<->}(0,0)(-4.5,-4.5)(4.5,4.5)
\psparametricplot[linecolor=green]{-360}{360}{t 2 exp cos 1 t sin sub mul t 2 exp sin 1 t cos add mul} 
\end{pspicture}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here: First PostScript works in degrees, while you want radians. You tried to compensate by adjusting the limits, but e.g. sin(360^2) in degrees is something completely different than sin((2pi)^2) in radians.

This can be fixed by converting from radians to degrees before running `sin` or `cos` by adding `RadtoDeg`.

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
\title{\textbf{\LARGE {Assignment}}}
\author{\emph {NEHA MALIK}}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,5)
\psaxes{<->}(0,0)(-4.5,-4.5)(4.5,4.5)
\psparametricplot[linecolor=green]{2 Pi mul neg}{2 Pi mul}{t 2 exp RadtoDeg cos 1 t RadtoDeg sin sub mul t 2 exp RadtoDeg sin 1 t RadtoDeg cos add mul} 
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

This produces
[image]

As you can see, the pst-plot default of evaluating a plot at 50 points is highly inadequate for this function. It looks better if we increase the number of points to 1500 with `plotpoints=1500`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
\title{\textbf{\LARGE {Assignment}}}
\author{\emph {NEHA MALIK}}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-5,-5)(5,5)
\psaxes{<->}(0,0)(-4.5,-4.5)(4.5,4.5)
\psparametricplot[linecolor=green,plotpoints=1500]{2 Pi mul neg}{2 Pi mul}{t 2 exp RadtoDeg cos 1 t RadtoDeg sin sub mul t 2 exp RadtoDeg sin 1 t RadtoDeg cos add mul} 
\end{pspicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Got it! Thank you soo muchh. 

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want?

```
\documentclass[svgnames, pstricks, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-4.4,-4.4)(6,6)
\psset{unit=4cm, algebraic, plotpoints=100, showorigin=false}
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,ticksize=0 4pt]{->}(0,0)(-1.1,-1.1)(1.5,1.5)[$x$,-120][$y$,210]
\psset{linewidth=1.5pt,algebraic, linecolor=IndianRed}
\psparametricplot{-0.6366}{0.6366}{cos(t^2)*(1-sin(t)) | sin(t^2)*(1 + cos(t))}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No... I tried finding the correct output and desmos says it is different from this.

Comment: @BinodKumar: Strange… There's no error message when I compile this code. Could you post how it should look like, according to Desmos?

Comment: Edited the question... Check it again please.